# Regex with wxwdigets

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2013, wxwidgets

I'm using the Google Translate API and obviously I want to parse the text translated. To do that, I'm using the regex class included in wxWidget.

This is my code with an example text:

```
wxRegEx             responseText = "\"translatedText\": \"(.*)\"";
    wxString text = responseText.GetMatch("{\n \"data\": {\n  \"translations\": [\n   {\n    \"translatedText\": \"Hello how are you?\"\n   }\n  ]\n }\n}\n");
```

But it doesn't work. Any advice? thank you!

Comment: sample input and expected output?

Comment: the sample is already added, and the expected output is the string translated: Hello how are you? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [example in the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_reg_ex.html) shows, you must call [Matches()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_reg_ex.html#a4f63e65c83d19d7f4115e0cb46d797f2) before using [GetMatch()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_reg_ex.html#a7b2b15b023a36603084a6b8b9fcf84fd) (this is also emphasized in the documentation of the latter itself!).

Answer (score 1):

Escape the escape character `\` to make them act like escape characters. Use the following

```
wxRegEx responseText = "\\"translatedText\\": \\"(.*)\\""
```

Comment: Even if I put in a simple regex, it doesn't work, ``translatedText(.*)``, for example.
 Your answer is true, I didn't realize about that, but is not correct. Check the number of slax, you have to use three, haven't you?

Comment: i am sorry.. i dint get you?